# Can I get Gerrit to notify me when a certain file type has been modified?

Tags: notifications, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I'm the only front-end dev on our team and I would like to be notified whenever one of the other devs pushes a review that touches some "front-end" files (e.g., *.html or *.css). Is this possible?

We're using Gerrit v2.9.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find any changes containing html files with following search (according to [docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#path)):

```
path:^.*\.html$
```

In my setup (Gerrit 2.12.2), I had to use (with trailing $, I've an error):

```
path:^.*\.html
```

Please note that you combine searches with boolean operators like `AND` and `OR`. Example:

```
path:^.*\.html OR path:^.*\.css
```

If you want to get notification, you can save this filter in your settings (Settings > Watched Projects). See [this documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-notify.html#user) for more details.

Comment: Merci vielmal, Urs :)